# How can I integrate my Turtle code to Tkinter window, while keeping the feature of screen update

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I have written below code originally for IMU sensor but to predict similar behaviour, I have commented IMU serial connection part and replaced it by random values.

This code works perfectly as I want but now I want to put this turtle window on Tkinter window while still using screen refresh part of my code.

```
import random
import tkinter
import turtle
class GUI():
    def parsedata():
#######################I wrote this code for IMU sensor, but as im posting it online
#######################Im replacing IMU serial code by random values because you will not have IMU #######################available 
        
#             packet = serialInst.read()
#             if packet[0] == 0x55:
#                 packet1 = serialInst.read()
#                 if packet1[0] == 0x55:
#                     datapacket = serialInst.read(180)
#                     
#                     roll = struct.unpack('<f', datapacket[31:35])[0]
#                     pitch = struct.unpack('<f', datapacket[35:39])[0]
#                     yaw = struct.unpack('<f', datapacket[39:43])[0]
                    
                    n = random.random()
                    o = random.random()
                    p = random.random()
                    data1=[500*n,500*o,10*p]
                    return data1

    def tracker():
        while True:
            data=GUI.parsedata()
            if data != None:

                x=data[0]
                y=data[1]
                yaw=data[2]
                #print(x,y)
                t.goto(x,y)
                t.setheading(yaw)
                t.pendown()
                turtle.update()
# 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    ############# Serial communication for IMU
#     serialInst = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")
#     serialInst.baudrate = 230400
#     serialInst.close()
#     serialInst.open()     
    ############# Serial Communication for IMU

#     root = tkinter.Tk()
#     canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
#     canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    screen=turtle.Screen()
    screen.mode('world')
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
    t=turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
    t.penup()
    t.showturtle()
    GUI.tracker()
```

In the above code, I have used this code snippet to refresh the screen. And now I want to integrate this whole above code on Tkinter window. Can someone pleasee help me.

```
screen=turtle.Screen()
    screen.mode('world')
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to adjust our turtle code from *standalone* to (tkinter) *embedded*:

```
import tkinter
from random import randrange
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle

class GUI():
    def parsedata():

        n = randrange(-250, 250)
        o = randrange(-250, 250)
        p = randrange(10)

        data = [n, o, p]

        return data

    def tracker():
        data = GUI.parsedata()

        if data is not None:
            x, y, yaw = data

            t.goto(x, y)
            t.setheading(yaw)
            t.pendown()

            screen.update()

        screen.ontimer(GUI.tracker)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x1000")
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=500, height=500)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

    screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
    screen.tracer(0, 0)

    t = RawTurtle(screen, visible=False)
    t.penup()

    GUI.tracker()

    screen.mainloop()
```

Also note that tkinter and turtle use different coordinate systems.  And don't use `while True:`.